# split string with regex into three separate variables

Tags: c#, regex

If I have a string in this format:

```
string placeholder = "[[Ford:Focus(blue)]]";
```

What regex could I use to populate the three variables below?

```
string make = ?
string model = ?
string colour = ?
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = "[[Ford:Focus(blue)]]";
var parts = Regex.Matches(input, @"\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

var make = parts[0];
....
```

OR

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\[\[(\w+):(\w+)\((\w+)\)\]\]");
var make = match.Groups[1].Value;
var model = match.Groups[2].Value;
....
```

Comment: Great...what though if colour was optional and it wasn't specified...is there a way in the regex to set it to empty string?

Comment: I suppose you could then use `\w*` instead of `\w+`.

Comment: @thegunner For the first regex, you can check the `Length` of *parts*, for the 2nd, you should give a sample input

Comment: If the "colour" part has a space it doesn't get pick up..e.g."light blue". Any suggestions?

Comment: @thegunner  then replace `\w+` with `[a-zA-Z ]+`